# React js- bootstrap Value not showing on Tab change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I am making a React App. I am using react-bootstrap to make it.But while trying to show content on different nav items by using the Tab.Content and Tab.Pane , the value shows in the default nav correctly on page refresh but if I go to the other nav item , the content does not show up and the content of the default value also gets blank.If i again refresh the page the value on the default nav item shows up and then the same thing happen. Please help me.
Error lies in between line 22 to line 29.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Tab, Nav } from 'react-bootstrap'
import Conversations from './Conversations'
import Contacts from './Contacts'


const Sidebar = (props) => {

    const [activeKey, setActiveKey] = useState('conversations')

    return (
        <div style={{ width: '250px' }} className='d-flex flex-column' >
            <Tab.Container activeKey={activeKey} onSelect={() => setActiveKey(null)} >
                <Nav variant='tabs' className='justify-content-center mt-1' >
                    <Nav.Item>
                        <Nav.Link eventKey='conversations'  >Conversations</Nav.Link>
                    </Nav.Item>
                    <Nav.Item>
                        <Nav.Link eventKey='contacts' >Contacts</Nav.Link>
                    </Nav.Item>
                </Nav>
                <Tab.Content  >
                    <Tab.Pane eventKey='conversations' >
                        <Conversations />
                    </Tab.Pane>
                    <Tab.Pane eventKey='contacts' >
                        <Contacts />
                    </Tab.Pane>
                </Tab.Content>
            </Tab.Container>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/tabs/#tabs-controlled , I suspect that:

```
onSelect={() => setActiveKey(null)}
```

should be:

```
onSelect={(key) => setActiveKey(key)}
```

Edit: I've tried this change out locally now and it appears to work.

Comment: Ok I will check that